# What are the do's and don'ts a Hindu (or any human being) should follow in Kali Yuga?

Tags: kali-yuga

I am assuming present time which we are living as [kali yuga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Yuga) and also it is the last of the four yugas.

These words were taken from [here](http://openrevolt.info/2012/09/01/kalki-the-next-avatar-of-god-and-the-end-of-kali-yuga/)

> It is said that everyone will become godless. Whatever devotees,
>   bhaktas, and sages are left on the planet will be so unique in
>   character and peculiar compared with the rest of society that they
>   will be ridiculed and hunted down in the cities for sport like
>   animals.Thus, they will flee the cities to live underground in caves
>   or high up in the mountains, or simply disengage from the earthly
>   plane of existence. In this way, they will disappear from the face of
>   the earth. That is the time when the dark influence of the age of
>   Kali-yuga will become so dominant that its full influence will
>   manifest without hindrance.

I know we cant prevent the ultimate fall to dark ages but Is there any duties which a Hindu or a human being should follow in this yuga.

Comment: I feel Kaliyuga to be region specific. If you go to some of the Scandinavian countries, you don't feel even a remote effect of so-called Kaliyuga. All kind of peculiar humans are being welcomed. Within various countries as well, there should be places possessing calmness.

Comment: @iammilind, you don't feel the effect of Kali Yuga in scandinavian countries where most people live like mlechas ??

Comment: @Eka, chant the nama of Bhagavan.

Comment: @ram, that's subjective. Many western people visit India then they make a point to visit slums to see how Indians stay in a highly constraint environments. Even well off Indians have highly dense homes, which is illegal in those countries due to minimum space rules. Yes we do have many temples as we believe in formful deva-s. They have less churches as many believe in formless deva (i.e. they worship natural elements). But that's not a deciding factor of being mlechchha.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question. Any intelligent person with three working brain cells should realize the craziness in the present world and ask the question as you have beautifully asked! I thank you.

The sages were worried about the Kali Yuga and they assembled at the beginning of Kali Yuga in Naimisranya to ask Suta Goswami this same question. In response to this, the text Srimad Bhagavatam was spoken by Suta Goswami to all present. [1] So as a Hindu, one would regularly read and apply Srimad Bhagavatam to counter the effects of Kali Yuga. [2]

In the Srimad Bhagavatam, the most essential instruction given is to the chant the names of Krishna. Infact that is the blessing of this age. Despite all the bad effects of Kali yuga, it has the greatest blessing that simply by chanting Krishna, one can be delivered from this material world.

> My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults, there is still one good > quality about this age: Simply by chanting the Hare Kṛṣṇa mahā-mantra, one can 
>   become free from material bondage and be promoted to the transcendental 
>   kingdom.[3]

1. Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 1, Chapter 1 https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/1
2. Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 1, Chapter 3, Text 43 https://www.vedabase.com/sb/1/3/43
3. Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 12 Chapter 3 Text 51 https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/51

Comment: It's spelled Suka Goswami. Moreover, the effects of Kali can be countered without Krishna.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Suta mahamuni is different from Suka, son of Vyasa. Read the first chapter of Bhagavatam. Sages question Suta. Suta speaks Bhagavatam. The answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

The Samanya dharma common to every one in every yuga are- Ahimsa, Satya, Asteya, Shaucham and Indriya Nigraha. Manu Smriti mentions these as the Samanya dharma. Many other also give simlar list.

For details regarding practice of each tenet, you may see here- http://www.newsgram.com/?s=gleanings+from+Hindu+Scriptures